# Command to turn on LED after finding word from array

Tags: api, twitter, led, intel-edison

Using Twitter's API, I have written a command to send an alert whenever a Tweet containing specific words is found in my news timeline. I would now, however, like to use this alert to turn on an LED grove that is attached to my edison board.

This is the code I am using:

```
var groveSensor = require('jsupm_grove');
var led = new groveSensor.GroveLed(3);
    led.on();
```

I am just not sure how to display it in my API. Currently, I have the code at the top, before the API, and then the "on" / 'off" command after each array. This has only resulted in the LED's remaining off, though.

```
var params = {screen_name: 'myusername'};
client.get('statuses/home_timeline', params, function(error, tweets, 
response) {
if (!error) {
for (var i=0;i<tweets.length;i++){
for (var ii=0;ii<techArray.length;ii++){
if(tweets[i].text.indexOf(techArray[ii])>-1&&tweets[i].id_str*1>lastId)
{
console.log("-----found a tech article - " + tweets[i].text + "-------" 
+ tweets[i].text.indexOf(techArray[ii]));
var led = new groveSensor.GroveLed(3);
led.on();
}
else {
var led = new groveSensor.GroveLed(3);
led.off();
}
```

Any idea where/how I should actually write this command?

Comment: Have you tried just turning the LED light on and off in a completely independent piece of code? And did it work there?

Comment: No I didn't. This was my first attempt. Any suggestions on how to write this piece of code independently?

Comment: Why can't you just create an LED.js file with the first 3 lines of the code here and then started it with node LED.js??